# How can I find a TeX Live repository for a certain version of TeX Live?

Tags: texlive, tlmgr, ctan

I have TeXLive 2022 installed on my system - it's my Linux distribution's default. If I run `tlmgr --gui`, and try to load the default repository (URL: `https://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texline/tlnet`) - I get an error, because at that URL the version is now 2023.

How can I get a URL appropriate for my version? (Or - am I wrong to try?)

Note: I would rather not upgrade.

Comment: The solution at the original question works also for TeXLive 2022, i.e. `tlmgr option repository ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2022/tlnet-final`.